# Reversing order of words in a sentence

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void reverse(char* sentence)
{
    int index = strlen(sentence) - 1;
    char last = '\0';
    int hold = 0;
    while ( index != 0){
        while (sentence[index] != ' ')
            index--;
        hold = index; //keeps the index of whitespace
        while (sentence[index] != last){
            cout << sentence[index]; //printing till it either hits end character or whitespace.
            index++;
        }
        last = sentence[hold]; //Keeps the whitespace
        index = hold; //
    }

}
int main()
{
    char* sentence = new char[256];
    cin.getline(sentence, 256);
    reverse(sentence);
}
```

I want to reverse the orders of words in a sentence and you can see my attempt above.

Sample intput and output should be like this:

```
Howdy Mr. Mcfly? 

Mcfly? Mr. Howdy
```

Where i get:

```
Howdy Mr. Mcfly?
 Mcfly?
```

There are many similar questions around the internet but what i want is to find error in my own code.

Comment: If you're using C++ why are you using char*?  This would be much easier with strings.  I noticed you tagged with "dynamic-arrays" is there some specific reason you're using char* that would make an answer that switched to using strings unacceptable?

Comment: what do you see when you run your example through a debugger?

Comment: Now would be a good time to start learn how to use a debugger. By stepping through the code and inspecting variables you should be able to find the bug(s) for yourself quite quickly.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware it would be easier with strings and other means but i'm simply practicing as a beginner.

Comment: Add each word to stack and start poping those suckers

Comment: Doing this in C is gonna be gross, and in my opinion not a useful exercise, unless you're trying to teach yourself why old style cstrings suck.  That being said, I would use a recursive approach, each call searching for a new whitespace character or the /0 character, then as you return back up the stack do work(add it to a list) with the word you found.  If you do this work after your recursive call, your words will be reversed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers suggest you should use `std::string` which can save lot of hassles.
But just for the note,

```
void reverse(char* sentence)
{
    int index = strlen(sentence) - 1,hold,last = '\0';
    /*For the 1st iteration last is `\0` for all others it is ` `*/
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        /*
        In your original code,
        This while loop(below) will continue to keep decrementing index 
        even below `0`,You wont exit this while loop until you encounter a ` `.
        For the 1st word of the sentence you will never come out of the loop.
        Hence the check, index>=0
        */

        while (index>=0 && sentence[index] != ' ')
        index--;

    /* You can print the whitespace later*/

    hold = index - 1;  // This keeps track of the last character 
                       // of preceding word 

    index++; //character after space

        while (sentence[index] != last)
    {
            cout << sentence[index]; 
            index++;
        }
    last = ' '; 
        index = hold; 

        /* Dont print space after 1st word*/
    if(index > 0)
    cout<<" ";
    }

}
int main()
{
    char* sentence = new char[256];
    cin.getline(sentence, 256);
    reverse(sentence);
    delete[] sentence; // Delete the allocated memory
}
```

<sub>Tryin to keep it as close to your logic</sub>

Comment: Just what i wanted, ty so much.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `std::string` `std::vector` and `std::reverse` to make things easier:

```
std::string sentence = "Your sentence which contains ten words, two of them numbers";
std::stringstream stream(sentence);
std::vector<std::string> words;
for ( std::string word; stream >> word; )
{
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

Now you have everything separated into words. You may now want to remove question marks or other punctuation, since the logic will be easier to implement while the words are still in the correct order. For reversing, do this:

```
std::reverse(words.begin(), word.end());
```

You'll need to include several headers:

```
#include <string> // for storing strings in a C++ way
#include <sstream> // to easily separate sentences into words
#include <vector> // to dynamically store arbitrary amounts of words
#include <algorithm> // for std::reverse
```

You can see this code in action with this [demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/SkniOi)

Comment: /* Dont print space after 1st word*/ <br/>
    if(index > 0) <br/>
    If the sentence begins with a single letter then a space wont be printed in the above check.<br/>It should be if(index>=0)

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Excuse me? I don't have anything like that in my answer / code. Can you enlighten me on what your comment is supposed to tell me?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    char sentence[256];
    std::cin.getline(sentence, 256);

    std::istringstream f(sentence );

    std::string s;  
    std::list<std::string> strings;

    while (f >> s) 
    {
        strings.push_front(s);
    }
}
```

at this moment `strings` contains the words in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
index = hold;
```

You hav ean infinite loop.  You're always going back to the point where you find your '\0' character I believe.  What you should do is have two separate while loops.  One to get you to the end of your character array, to find '\0'.  And then another set of loops to return back to white space, then loop back forward printing out characters.

NOTE: I like all the answers presented better, but this is why the code you posted is failing.  Here is a version of this function that works with just cstrings.

```
void reverse(char* sentence, const int START)
{
    if(sentence[START] == '\0') return;
    char last = '\0';
    int hold = 0;
    int index = START + 1;


    while(sentence[index] != '\0' && sentence[index] != ' ') {//There are better ways to do this logic, but I wanted to remain true to your implementation as much as possible
        index++;
    }

    reverse(sentence, index);
    for(int j = START; j < index; j++) {
        cout << sentence[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
```

I prints out a few extra end lines, you can of course format the output however you like, the hard part is done.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the earlier version, *firmly tongue-in-cheek* :)

Note that the program reads all of stdin, treating each individual line as a 'sentence'.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phx= boost::phoenix;
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    auto out = std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ");

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(std::cin), l;
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    parse(f, l, 
            (
              (as_string [ +~char_("\n\t ") ] % +char_("\t ")) 
                    [ phx::reverse(_1), phx::copy(_1, phx::ref(out)) ]
            ) % eol [ phx::ref(std::cout) << "\n" ]
         );
}
```

Comment: this reverses the whole sentence character by character, not word by word.

Comment: ah, you're quite right :) oh well, using Boost Range I'd fix that _and_ make it more elegant, but I guess that kind of exceeds the scope of useful answers...

Comment: well I'm personally not a fan of boost, but others might disagree. Let's see your boost approach ;-)

Comment: @stefan There, dinner came in the way :/ However, the result is a near-oneliner. This is obviously the most straightforward solution :)

Comment: dafuq did I just read? I simply _can't_ tell if this is correct. Well, I'll just trust that his is actually working code (I don't have boost installed, so I can't even check), but I'd never recommend doing it this way: In my opinion, the intent of code should be directly visible.

Comment: @stefan LOL. I sure hope you didn't miss the point about relative positions of the _lingua_ and _buccae_ :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use stack. 
1.Tokenize the string using delimiter("")
2. push the word into the stack
3. As you pops up, store that word in the new string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used splitting (tokenizing) sentence into words and then use that for reverse printing. Hope this help-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(char* str, char delimiter=' ')
{
        vector<string> result;
        do
        {
                char* begin =str;
                while(*str != delimiter && *str)
                        str++;
                result.push_back(string(begin, str));
        }while(0 != *str++);
        return result;
}
int main()
{
        string str;
        vector<string> tempStr;
        cout<<"Enter The String: ";
        getline(cin, str);
        cout<<endl;
        tempStr=split((char*)str.c_str());
        str.clear();
        cout<<"Final Reverse: \n";
        for(int i=tempStr.size()-1; i>=0; i--) str+=tempStr.at(i)+" ";
                //cout<<tempStr.at(i)<<" ";
        cout<<str<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by istringstream class of C++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,st,w;
    int i;
    getline(cin,s);
    istringstream is(s);
    st="";
    is>>st;
    while(is>>w)
    {
        st=w+' '+st;
    }
    cout<<st<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```