# Going to the new c++11 standards

Tags: c++, c++11

[CODE-JAM 2010 PROBLEM](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1):

Given a list of space separated words, reverse the order of the words.

> **INPUT**:
>
> The first line of input gives the number of cases, N. N test
>   cases follow.
>
> **OUTPUT**:
>
> For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: "
>   followed by the list of words in reverse order.
>
> **Limits**:
>
> N <= 5
>
> **INPUT**:
>
> ```
> 3                                         
>
> this is a test                            
>
> foobar                                    
>
> all your base
> ```
>
> OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> Case #1: test a is this
>
> Case #2: foobar
>
> Case #3: base your all
> ```

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
class prog {
char str[50];
public:
  void getdata()
  {
    gets(str);  
  }
  void rev();
  void srev();
  void display()
  {
    cout<< str;
  }


};

void prog::srev()
{   
  int i,j,len;
  char temp;
  len=strlen(str);
  for(i=0,j=len-1;i<len/2;i++,j--)
    {
      temp=str[i];
      str[i]=str[j];
      str[j]=temp;
    }           
}

void prog::rev()
{

  int i,k=0;
  char word[50];
  strcat(str," ");
  for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
      if(str[i]!=' ')
        {
          word[k]=str[i];
          k++;
        }
      else
        {
          while(k>0)
            {
              cout<<word[--k];
            }
          cout<<str[i];
        }
    }
}

void main()
{         clrscr();
  fstream file;
  int n;
  cout<<"\n\n\t";
  cin>>n;
  prog p[10];
  file.open("cj.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cout<<"\n\t";
      p[i].getdata();
      file.write((char*)&p[i],sizeof(p[i]));
    }
  file.seekg(0);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cout<<"\n\n\t";
      p[i].srev();
      p[i].rev();
    }
}
```

I wrote this program in c++98 version, with turbo 3.0 as the IDE. It worked fine giving the desired ouput in the desired limits.

My question is, as C++ has rolled out C++11 Standard, what changes I have to do in my above code?

Also, can anyone provide me some good links to read out about the exact implementations in the libraries, as the changes must be innumerous, at one place?

Comment: Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991. Are you sure it's C++98? The telling signs that someone is using Turbo C++ are usually `conio.h`, `iostream.h`, and `void main`. You don't have to make many changes to get your program to compile in C++03 or C++11. First off, I would suggest checking out [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) and [github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) for a copy of the standard. Secondly, I would update your compiler or use an online compiler.

Comment: Third, see [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Asking for `good links` isn't really fit for this site considering Stackoverflow is a resource in of itself if you cannot find anything on Google, which is doubtful. And finally, you will probably end up rewriting your code, not so much because it's "C++98" code, but because once you become familiar with C++11 idioms and the facilities of the standard library, your coding style will completely change. Writing a one-to-one correlation for bad code will still result in bad code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and therefore belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @stefan Also because the problem is "reverse the order of words in a sentence", it is almost certainly a duplicate as well. Which is ironic, because you wrote an answer to that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17026996/1508519)!

Comment: @remyabel: this is not a duplicate. i am asking a solution to my question. my code is correct and works fine with the desired output. I just needed to know how to revise it to the new standards, and what implementations i have to made.

Comment: @CS101 I'm not calling it a duplicate because the question is the same, I'm calling it a duplicate because there are idiomatic implementations that you can find by searching the problem.

Comment: @remyabel: But a c++ online compiler, usually has c++11 as it standard.

Comment: @CS101 [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) will allow you to change the invocation. You can do `g++ -std=c++98` for example.

Comment: @remyabel Didn't remember that one :D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generic code review; however, you should narrow your question down before putting it on [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 2):

For a more idiomatic approach, please see [Reversing order of words in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026740/reversing-order-of-words-in-a-sentence). I modified Stefan's answer a little bit:

```
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::string sentence = "Your sentence which contains ten words, two of them numbers";
  std::istringstream stream(sentence);
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::back_inserter(words));
  std::reverse(words.begin(), words.end());
  for ( size_t i(0); i < words.size(); ++i )
  {
    std::cout << words[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Also, since the problem from what I understand specifies a max amount of letters/words that will be given, you can get rid of `std::reverse`:

```
  words.resize(20); // replace 20 with max amount
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    words.rbegin());
```

Two other contrived examples:

```
  std::reverse_copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
  std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Oh I See, a fan of ostream/istream iterators ;-) Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs considerable revision to follow C++98. At least offhand, I don't see any reason it would need further revision to follow C++11, though you might be able to make the code a little more readable using some of the new features of C++11.

In C++98/03, I'd probably write the code something like this:

```
int main() { 
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(line, std::cin);
        std::istringstream in(line);

        std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in)),
                                        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

        std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), 
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    }
}
```

In going to C++11, the primary change I'd make would be to use "uniform initialization":

```
        std::vector<std::string> words{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                                       std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};
```

A few people have written code to (for one example) use a range-based `for` loop in cases like this, so the loop would end up something like:

```
for (auto i : range(0, num))
```

I guess if you had a lot of other code that could use this, it might be worthwhile, but I see little point in it for one loop.